# cucumber.js step definition failing with timeout error in first step

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I have a scenario where in I have to login in the website and perform some validations, below is my feature file-

```
Feature:
As a developer
I need to validate 
The login functionality and Home Page of common-core workflow

Scenario: Check title and number of apps on Home Page
    Given I login into myWebsite 
    Then I expect that the title of the page is "Welcome to My WebSite"
    And Number of apps is 7
    Then Number of apps in left drawer has count 8
```

The step definition file is as below-

```
Given(/^I login into myWebsite/, function() {
loginPage.login();
});

Then(/^I expect that the title of the page is "Welcome to My WebSite"/, 
function() {
homePage.waitForPageLoad();
homePage.homePageTitle.should.be.equal("Welcome to My WebSite");
});

Then(/^Number of apps is (\d+)/, function(count) {
expect(homePage.allApps.length).to.be.equal(7);
});

Then(/^Number of apps in left drawer has count (\d+)/, function(count) {
expect(homePage.navDrawerLeftArray.length).to.be.equal(count);
});
```

I have used page object model to fetch web elements and Chai.js for assestions.

When I execute the above steps I get error-

```
[chrome #0-0]     Check title and number of apps on Home Page
[chrome #0-0]       1) I login into myWebsite product
[chrome #0-0]       !! I expect that the title of the page is "Welcome to My 
WebSite"
[chrome #0-0]       !! Number of apps is 7
[chrome #0-0]       !! Number of apps in left drawer has count 8
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 3 pending (59s)
[chrome #0-0] 1 failing
[chrome #0-0]
[chrome #0-0] 1) Check title and number of apps on Home Page6 I login into 
myWebsite:
[chrome #0-0] function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 30000 
milliseconds
[chrome #0-0] Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 
30000 milliseconds
[chrome #0-0]     at Timeout._onTimeout 
(Project_Path\user_code_runner.js:93:22)
[chrome #0-0]     at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
[chrome #0-0]     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
[chrome #0-0]     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing that could be the issue...

You are using regular expressions wrongly, from what i can see anyway

```
Then I expect that the title of the page is "Welcome to My WebSite"
```

from your feature file is correct however when you put this back into your step definitions, do something like this instead of what you are doing

```
Then("I expect that the title of the page is {string}", 
function => {
```

That will pass the string "Welcome to My WebSite" from your feature file into your step definitions file, I'm assuming if you remove the regular expressions from your original test this will probably allow it to pass, at the moment i think it's confused as to what test to run due to your usage of regular expressions.

Also add something like this to your tests to ensure the page isn't trying to load the script before the elements have loaded.

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(pageElement), 10000)
```

Lastly, you aren't dealing with unhandled promises which will make the code work in odd ways an example of me dealing with a promise is below, i'll post a step definition and a feature line to match so you know how i'm doing things.

The step definition:

```
   Given("I open the page with the url {string} and route {string}", (url, route, next) => {
    driver.get(`${url}${route}`).then(() => {
        next();
    }).catch(ex => {
        console.log(ex);
    });
});
```

and the feature line to match..

```
Given I open the page with the url "http://localhost:3000" and route "/login"
```

hopefully these will at least make your testing better standards, the reason you would use cucumber is to pass data from the feature file into your step definitions file in order to use the same step definition for multiple features/scenarios.

Let me know if i can be of any more help.

Comment: The problem is, code is not executing any line after 'loginPage.login();'.

Comment: Oh, one last thing then.. try this...
`Given(/^I login into myWebsite/, function(next) {
loginPage.login();
next();
});`

This will allow for the program to always run a next, if you look in my code i posted originally you will see more use cases of it.

Comment: I added a callback to given hook as suggested by got an error -

    function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces: callback and promise
    to use the callback interface: do not return a promise
    to use the promise interface: remove the last argument to the function

Comment: @AvinashSalimath Did you find solution.? I am seeing the same error what you mentioned in comment..

Comment: @FayazMd: Yes, I used the regular expressions instead of "Welcome to My WebSite" in step def

Comment: Perfect, alternatively, you might have also tried with escaping double quotes (which workd for me). Anyway, thanx for reply with solution.